# Why does R htmlwidget from saveWidget have such long script src arg?

Tags: r

Observe the following source generating using `htmlwidgets::saveWidget`. The `<script>` tag's `src` argument is *very* long. Why is this, and is there an option in `saveWidget` to shorten it?

view-source:http://www.aplaceformom.com/blog/wp-content/static/redfin-study/redfin-apfm-number-years-by-care-type.html

Answer (score 0):

`saveWidget` by default base64 encodes all the links and scripts for standalone HTML files.  To avoid this, use `saveWidget(..., standalone = FALSE).  Here is the relevant code https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/blob/master/R/savewidget.R#L16.